# NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery. when I build spring boot jar with gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

My module's gradle configuration is following,

```
group 'com.ifox.platform'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":ifox-base-service")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

If I gradle build with above configuration, I will get a jar file. Then I excute it:

```
javar -jar xxxx.jar
```

It's successful and I can visit my website:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

But when I test method named listAll(), there is a exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query;
```

At this time, maybe you think it's my low-level code fault. I modified my gradle configuration, like this:

```
group 'com.ifox.platform'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":ifox-base-service")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Yes, I removed the spring boot plugin configuration. Then I test my method(listAll) again, it's successful to get all data from database.
How to fix it?
It's my low-level code fault, or spring-boot plugin configuration fault?

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the failure? The Spring Boot plugin will be ensuring that a particular version of Hibernate is being used. I would guess that something else in your app is not compatible with that version of Hibernate

Comment: My configuration is, springVersion=4.3.9.RELEASE
springBootVersion=1.5.4.RELEASE
hibernateVersion=5.2.10.Final ... all of framework is latest version.

Comment: Can you give me a list of compatible version?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you very much. I have resolved this issue. You are right, because of Hibernate version. I find spring-boot plugin(1.5.4) depend on Hibernate 5.0 default, but I configured Hibernate 5.2 before. BTW do you know how to improve Hibernate version to 5.2 ?